# .Net Core API Returning StreamContent with request object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to return an excel file from a Web API, but the I'm getting a JSON Response instead of a file getting downloaded.

```
using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Placments");

            var taxonomyConnStr = GetConnectionString(DatabaseSettings.ConnectionStringNames.Taxonomy);
            var plookConnStr = GetConnectionString(DatabaseSettings.ConnectionStringNames.Plook);
            var content = _repo.GetPlacementDataTable(masterAgencyDivisionId, masterClientId, plookConnStr);



            if (content.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Color colFromHex = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");

                sheet.Row(1).Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                sheet.Row(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colFromHex);
                sheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
                sheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
                sheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Size = 12;

                sheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(content, true);

                sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

            }
            else
            {
                sheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromText("There is no data for filtered results. Please adjust your selections.");
            }

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            excel.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-sream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Report.xlsx"

            };

            return result;

        }
```

And here is my AJAX Call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
           window.location = "https://localhost:44318/custom/GetPlacementExcel/6/77";
           })
})
```

But the response I'm getting is :

> {"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":["attachment; filename=Report.xlsx"]},{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/octet-stream"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asp.Net Core no longer uses `HttpResponseMessage` so you need to use the appropriate action result to return the desired data.

Since you are already storing the data in a stream, returning a `FileStreamResult` with a proper mine type and file name should suit your needs.

```
public IActionResult MyAction() {

    //...code removed for brevity

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    excel.SaveAs(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var fileName = "Report.xlsx";
    var mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    //return the data stream as a file
    return File(stream, mimeType, fileName); //<-- returns a FileStreamResult

}
```

Comment: Minor nit, but MIME type should be `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Comment: @MarkG I just put what they had in the original code. Can easily update it. :P